# Complex cascade deletion with Entity Framework's Code First

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with Code First and I have a problem with cascade deletes. Since my model isn't a small one, I needed to turn them off, because otherwise there would be some circular deletion, which SQL Server couldn't resolve.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Afterwards, I manually specified which entities should cascade delete using the Fluent API, e.g.:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<First>().HasRequired(x => x.Second).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

However, I have encountered problems during testing.

Here's what the model looks like. Letters A to F represent the entities and the arrows point to the next entity that should be deleted in the chain (more like a tree, but I simplified it to point out where the problem is).

The problem is that one entity in the middle cannot be deleted, because an entity at its end contains a foreign key to the entity in the middle. Even though both entities would be deleted anyway, SQL Server refuses the deletion.

- A -- cascade --> B
- B -- cascade --> C
- C -- cascade --> D
- C -- cascade --> E
- D -- cascade --> E
- E -- cascade --> F (F contains D_ID)

Here's a picture to make it easier to understand: http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2015/03/16/deletion_treee3udl.png

When I try deleting entity "A", I get the following message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.F_dbo.D_Id\"

This is pretty annoying, since SQL Server should be able to figure out that both "D" and "F" can safely be deleted when deletion of A is requested.

How would you solve this problem? Keep in mind that the model is a bit more complex than this and that similar cases get repeated thought the model. You can assume that there are no circular cascade deletes in the model, because such cases are dealt with manually.

Comment: I think that cascading deletes is off in SQL by default, make sure that you allow that in the database, otherwise sql will throw an error. You can confirm this by deleting the record in question using ssms (assuming you can).  Also, I usually remove the backward navigation prop that entity creates by default, which often is the cause of your circular issue.

Comment: Code First creates entities with cascade deletes on, I'm quite sure about that. Like I already said in my post: I turned cascade deletes off and added cascade deletes manually for the entities I needed. When trying to delete an entity which should now trigger a series of cascade deletes, I receive that  error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your last sentence is saying because your problem is *precisely* that you have a circular dependency in your model: D -> E -> F -> D

Since referential integrity is *always* preserved there is no way that your delete can succeed as long as that circular dependency is there. This can be broken while leaving the FK relationship if for instance D_Id in every F row to be deleted is null. It will work then as for the rows affected the circularity has gone.

Circular dependencies are not a good sign of a quality design. I would urge you to rethink them.

Comment: Sorry, I made a couple of mistakes while describing the model (list of cascade deletes + tree view). Could you have another look?

What I wanted to say is that there are no cascade deletion circles like: A -- cascade --> B -- cascade --> C -- cascade --> A.

BTW, I'm creating a REST service according to a contract, which I have to obey. Rethinking the whole model is out of the question. The only thing I could do is implement it differently on the server side without exposing those differences on the service itself.

Comment: So is the linked diagram wrong, then? As described and diagrammed you have a circular relationship D -> E -> F -> D.